# Fried Liver Attack in the Scotch Gambit - Two Knights Defense?

Tags: opening, scotch-game, fried-liver-attack

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 exd4 4. Bc4 Nf6 5. Ng5 d5 6. exd5 Nxd5 7. Nxf7 Kxf7 8. Qf3+ Ke6
```

Now the usual move in the Fried Liver Attack is `9. Nc3` attacking the knight on `d5`, but the `d`-pawn heads this off. Is the Fried Liver Attack still viable in the Scotch Gambit/Two Knights Defense?

Comment: The whole line looks very suspect. I'm at work, but at least 5...Ne5, 7...Qe7+ and 7...Bb4+ seem worth checking first. I've never seen 5.Ng5 in the Scotch Gambit.

Comment: This opening just transposed into a Lolli Attack (variation of fried liver with d4 instead of Nxf7), where black has played poorly and white is in a much better position. White castles here.. threats things such as Re1, Bf4 and Nc3! (sacrificing for clearance)

Answer (score 4):

Given the moves in your post, the position favors White.  I think most White players would enjoy the seeing the Black King out there, suffering a pin, sitting on an open file, and flapping in the breeze on move 8 with Queens on the board.

Here's what Stockfish thinks after a reasonably long think:

```
[fen ""]
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.d4 exd4 4.Bc4 Nf6 5.Ng5 d5 6.exd5 Nxd5 7.Nxf7 Kxf7 8.Qf3+ Ke6 
 9.O-O Ne5 10.Re1 c6 11.Bf4 Bd6 12.Qg3 Qf6 13.Nd2 Re8 14.Nf3 Kf7 15.Nxe5+ Kg8 16.Nd3 Rxe1+ 17.Rxe1 Bf8 18.Be5 Qh6 19.Bxd4 Be6 20.Bb3 a5 21.a4 Bf7 22.h3 Rd8 23.Ne5
```

...with a small advantage for White.  I see both players having a good game here.  However, I suspect Black is walking a tightrope.  That is, to maintain parity, Black must play *much* better than White.

Answer (score 3):

It's better to castle on move 7 and sacrifice the knight next move. Black will have a hard time defending against this.

The variation with `5.Ng5` is called the Perreux Variation and is extensively analysed at the following site: 
[The Perreux Variation of the Two Knights Defense](http://www.rci.rutgers.edu/~goeller/urusov/perreux/)

A critical line begins with `6...Qe7+!`

```
   [fen ""]

   1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bc4 Nf6 4.d4 exd4 5.Ng5 d5 6.exd5 Qe7+!
```

White might have to respond `7.Kf1`, see the analyses given in the link.

Comment: Good answer.  Buried in the link you gave is one of my favorite games: [Morphy-NN 1-0, New Orleans Blindfold Simul](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1224558).  Morphy's moves in that game are perfect, even per modern computers (with sufficient analysis).